# Range Validator problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a GridView with a textbox in one of its fields. I use a range validator to make sure the user enters only "x" character:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMP3Master" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MP3Master") %>' BorderStyle="None" Width="80%" MaxLength="1" onchange="JSSaveNTSChanges(this);"></asp:TextBox>  
<asp:RangeValidator ID="MP3MasterRangeValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMP3Master" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="MP3 Master can be nothing but 'x'" Text="*" MinimumValue="x" MaximumValue="x" ValidationGroup="InsertUpdateNewTitlesStatusValidation">
</asp:RangeValidator>
```

The validator displays "*" on invalid input, but JSSaveNTSChanges() is still called. I want this function call blocked on invalid input. BTW, CompareValidator works correctly in other fields and blocks corresponding functions from being called.
Is it possible to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `CompareValidator` instead of `RangeValidator`.

Here is what I have tested on my end. Just try it..

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CompareValidator"
        ValueToCompare="x"  ControlToValidate="txtMP3Master"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: The CompareValidators that work in other fields are checking data type, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your function JSSaveNTSChanges will be called before or after the validator validation. But I recommend one of the 2 options below:

1. Move the JSSaveNTSChanges in the submit button click.
2. Call this function in a custom validator with EnableClientValidation = true

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot use submit button, and I don't even have any.